# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when updating a label in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fatal-error

my codes are as below, but i'm getting an error the same as the title for the line commented out. i tried optional binding but still isn't working. i'm already updating the dates array in `viewDidLoad` so not sure why its found nil, any idea? Thanks!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("logCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! logViewCell

   let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yy"
    // cell.date.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dates[indexPath.row])       
}
```

the codes for my custom cell:

```
class LogViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var date: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: could you please paste the code for the custom cell if any?

Comment: Either `cell` is `nil` or `cell.date` is `nil`. Set a breakpoint to find out.

Comment: I would think myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is coming up nil since this is the only spot where an unwrap is happening

Comment: After i changed the reusableIdentifier of the cell, it worked once. I then rearranged the layout of the label in my cell and reconnect it to the cell class. It hasn't worked since then, even if I changed the identifier.

Comment: and i think the cell is returning nil, but i have no idea why.

Comment: Have you registered your call with the tableView in viewDidLoad? Also you should use a single instance of the date formatter instead of creating it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Its a costly operation and its better to create it once, set the formatter string and then use it.

Comment: i solved it! somehow the line self.myTableView.registerClass(TestingPrivateLogViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "logCell") in viewDidLoad is causing it

Comment: @PradeepK i researched about your suggestion of creating a reusable formatter, I think its an excellent idea! but i don't know how to cache a nsdateformatter? please help

Comment: You can use a `static var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()` property in the ViewController and use it as `ViewController.dataFormatter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad register you class as

`self.myTableView.registerClass(LogViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"logCell")
ViewController.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yy"`

In your view controller declare a static property

`static var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()`

Then change your function to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    if let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("logCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? LogViewCell {
            cell.date.text = ViewController.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dates[indexPath.row])       
        } else {
          print("Could not get the required cell") 
          return nil
        }
    }
```